# How do I calculate angular momentum given constant torque?

Tags: angular-momentum, torque

Suppose I have a wheel that is initially at rest at $t = 0$ and a constant torque $\tau$ is tangentially applied to it. I want to measure the angular momentum of the system at time $t$. Would I calculate this as $\tau * t$? I think this is true as torque is measured as the change in angular momentum over time, and since it is initially at rest, $\tau = \frac{L}{t}$.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: that is right....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Newton's Law:
$$\tau = \frac{\Delta L}{\Delta t}$$
Since the wheel is initially at rest, $L_{\text{initial}}=0$ and so,
$$\tau =\frac{L}{t}$$
which implies
$$\boxed{L=\tau t}$$

Hope this helps. Ask anything if not clear :)

Comment: Great explanation. Thanks.

Comment: @greenfrog: My pleasure.